# Does Nettys GlobalEventExecuter utilize the current Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

According to Nettys Docs the [GlobalEventExecutor](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/GlobalEventExecutor.html) is a

> Single-thread singleton EventExecutor

which means that is uses one thread and has only one instance. I use the GlobalEventExecutor inside of a new Thread. Does the class always use the current thread or does it use one thread for everything?

If the second is right it would mean that using the GlobalEventExecutor inside a Thread-Pool doesn't really make sense. I would use the Thread-Pool for my Promises instead but I would have to make it global like the GlobalEventExecutor.

How am I to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GlobalEventExecutor` is a single thread based event executor.

This class will [start a new thread](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/concurrent/GlobalEventExecutor.java#L214) if needed when a new task is submitted. This thread isn't shared with the thread that executes the code.

Even if you call this global instance from multiple classes, it will only use a single thread on the background for the execution of tasks.

When this class detects that no tasks have been submitted for a while, it will shut down its internal thread, and recreates it when needed again. This time by default is 1 second.

*[This can be verified by looking at the source of GlobalEventExecutor](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/b7e947709ef28f0e60177f99298ef137ea46f18c/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/concurrent/GlobalEventExecutor.java).*

Comment: I should use Promises with my own thead pool inside of a theadpool? Or is there an advantage of using the GobalEventEventexecutor?

Comment: Rethinking the whole situation ended up in the following thoughts: The GlobalEventExecutor instance inside of the promise is only responsible for firing the future event. It has nothing to do with the actual execution of business logic. so using it inside of my own threadpool is completely ok or am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: Using it in your own thread pool is completely ok, but it is better to use the channels executer (`ctx.exec()`) instead of the global executor when scheduling the events to minimize the amount of thread context switches